# F# - FSharp.Data.SqlClient – How to specify timeout for Update

Tags: sql-server, f#, fsharp.data.sqlclient

I use `FSharp.Data.SqlClient` type providers to access SQL server database. So, I set up the types in F# something as follows:

```
type ClmDB = SqlProgrammabilityProvider<ClmSqlProviderName, ConfigFile = AppConfigFile>
type ResultDataTable = ClmDB.dbo.Tables.ResultData
type ResultDataTableRow = ResultDataTable.Row
```

and then I use it something like that:

```
let saveResultData (r : ResultData) (conn : SqlConnection) =
    let t = new ResultDataTable()
    let newRow = r.addRow t
    t.Update(conn) |> ignore
    newRow.resultDataId
```

where `ResultData` is some type, which "knows" how to convert itself into a row of `ResultDataTable` (`ResultDataTableRow`). The extension `r.addRow t` does that.

Everything is great, except that the row that I am inserting might be fairly large (25-30 MB in size) and so, I have a bad feeling that `t.Update(conn)` might randomly time out especially due to nearly 100% processor load (the computational system core is designed to consume all processing resources, though at low priority). Hovering over `t.Update` does not show any way to specify a timeout and any timeout at the level of connection is related, well, to a connection, not to the insert transaction ☹.

So, the question is how to specify timeout for an `Update` transaction.

Thanks a lot!

**20190116** update - So far `t.Update(conn)` above is holding up without timeouts on my machine while inserting 95MB data rows at 100% below normal load of some *other* stuff running there. I have not yet measured the actual time for such transactions. If I do, then I will update this.

Comment: Hi, have you try to add timeout on connections string ? I m looking about FSharp.Data.SqlClient but i didn’t see parameters .

Comment: @pascalsanchez According to specification, connection string time out is for connection to open, not for the command to execute: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectiontimeout?view=netframework-4.7.2 :( But, with the absence of anything else it is worth a try.

Comment: Sorry . Yes i have try to read thoses documentation today but i didn't find relevant information. i'm take time to look. 
By this issues https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/issues/98 they mention the existance off CommandTimeout

Comment: @pascalsanchez I am looking at the source: https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/blob/master/src/SqlClient/DataTable.fs#L78-L79 and it looks that command time out for table `Update` is **not set** :(

Comment: I have see the same. You didn’t have way to change your code for use some other functions that provided timeout ? Or other way was to open issues on github i thibk it’s the good way.      Îm sorry for bad helping but i didn’t work using F# at today.

Comment: @pascalsanchez Thanks for your help. I opened a ticket with developer: https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/issues/324 Let's see if they reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot specify timeout for `Update` method of a provided `DataTable` because the current Type Provider implementation does not provision for such feature.

However, as [the documentation](http://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.SqlClient/data%20modification.html) notes you may have few options for customizing the default behavior.

In addition, as your use case resembles an insert of a single row into the table I'd stick to an implementation with the help of `SqlCommandProvider` using its constructor's  `commandTimeOut` optional parameter for setting the desired timeout value `timespan`, as in a snippet below:

```
type AddRow = SqlCommandProvider<"path to the parameterized INSERT statement", designTimeConnection> 
..............................
(new AddRow(runTimeConnection, commandTimeOut=timespan)).Execute(...arg=value...) |> ignore
```

Comment: Yeah. I really do not want to go that way as this effectively requires writing SQL statements in F#. I don’t think that this is a proper way to go.

On the other side, I cannot specify a timeout for `Update` method unless I fork and actually **do** that. Given that I already have "local" bug fixes for two open source F# / C# projects, that would make it third ☹. Which means that I will have at least three sources, which I would have to manually reconcile with the repos. This is getting gross ☹. I opened a ticket with the developers and let’s see if it works out.

Comment: @KonstantinKonstantinov: Well, the up to date experience of using this TP in enterprise production context indicates that usual use pattern comes down to _ADO with statically controlled record structure and field types_. Entities as the custom `DataTable` cater more for non-production usage kind of exploratory programming and consciously may not carry certain features. For example, lack of asynchronicity support in `DataTable` methods.

Comment: The asynchronous "support" is a no-brainer in F# due to `async {...}` structure, `MailboxProcessor`, etc... So, I don't think that we need this C#-like zoo of sync/async methods in F# . My point is that currently if I want a timeout on table `Update` method, then the only way to get that (thanks to open source) is to clone the repo and just "make it happen". On the positive side, I think that I am not (yet) hitting timeouts inserting 30 MB rows of binary data. Perhaps it is worth moving such BLOBs into a file storage but this is beyond this question.

Comment: It would be in the true spirit of OSS if you, instead of forking and keeping locally, will submit PRs for the bugs and features you've addressed, indeed.

Comment: I did that for both of the local forks. Since nothing happened with the open tickets for months I just moved on. Here is one bug: https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/issues/595 It's been out for about 5 months :(

Comment: I finally gave up, generated SQL INSERT / UPDATE statements (I only needed to do that for two "data heavy" tables with under 20 columns each), copy-pasted to F#, replaced some SQL stuff, added connection timeout, and under 15 minutes the whole thing is kicking and screaming with no changes to the callers! Thanks again for the advice!